# Alpha blending with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl

What's the best way?

I tried to do this naïvely with a fragment shader that looks like this:

```
varying lowp vec4 color;
void main()
{
    lowp vec4 alpha = colorVarying.wwww;
    const lowp vec4 one = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    lowp vec4 oneMinusAlpha = one-alpha;
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor*oneMinusAlpha + colorVarying*alpha;
    gl_FragColor.w = 1.0;
}
```

But this doesn't work, because it seems gl_FragColor does not contain anything meaningful before the shader runs.

What's the correct approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alpha blending is done for you. On shader exit, `gl_FragColor` should hold the alpha value in `w` component and you have to set the blending mode with the normal API just like there is no shader at all. For example `gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,0.5)` will result in a green, 50% transparent fragment.

Comment: Gah. Talk about not seeing the forest for the trees. Thank you.